# How to use relative paths reading data from a directory on a mac in R?

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I am writing code that needs to work for users in both mac and windows. All users have a local copy of the google drive directory on their machine. I have a piece of code that automatically sets the working directory to the source file location. Lets call this directory "directory1". Within directory1 there is a folder called "directory2" which contains the data file.

the following piece of code works on all users using windows machines, with the working directory set to directory1,

```
data = read.csv(file="directory2\\filename", header=F)
```

however the following code does not work for at least some users on a mac

```
data = read.csv(file="directory2/filename", header=F)
```

I have verified that the mac users do have the working directory set to directory1 and that there is a a directory2 located in their directory1, and that all spelling is correct. However, they get a warning saying that directory2 does not exist. All users with this issue are using Rstudio. I asked the user to include the full path, and that did work. Can you not use relative paths on a mac in Rstudio? I've also tried ./ and / to start the relative path, but neither of those work either.

Comment: I use relative directories all the time. They work fine (with the syntax you have provided). If they really are in `directory1` and there really is a `directory2` with a file called `filename` they should be able to run `list.files(recursive = TRUE)` and get `[1] "directory2/filename"` back (prbly more if more files/dirs).

Comment: I agree with @hrbrmstr on relative paths.  Your user can open up the terminal, drag the file into that window, and it will provide the full path, which can then be pasted into the quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you tried `data <- read.csv(file=file.path("directory2", "filename"), header=F)` ? `file.path` is supposed to work across platforms.