# find path to file in parallel directory based on location of R script

Tags: r, path

I need to find the path to a data file in a parallel directory from the executing R script using relative paths. I can obtain the wording directory of the executing R script using `getwd()`, returning something like `"/main/project/scripts"`. I need to obtain a data resource located at `"/main/project/data/mydata.csv". I could use regex or some other form string manipulation to get this path, but is there a more natural way to change directories from within R? I have found several [SO resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845976/how-to-use-relative-paths-reading-data-from-a-directory-on-a-mac-in-r) for obtaining the working directory, but I was unable to find any questions on finding parallel resources.

psuedo code that fails:

```
# get working directory
wd<-getwd()
# use wd string to move up and then down in parallel directory
fp<-paste(wd, "/../data/mydata.csv", sep="") 
# import data
mydata <- read.csv(fp)
head(mydata)
```

Comment: (a) you don't need to `paste` on to your current working directory---your current working directory is "already there" unless you use a full file path. (b) You don't need to start with a `/`. (c) So try `fp = "../data/mydata.csv"`. (d) But you might generally do better to use Rstudio projects and the `here` package, initializing the Rstudio project in your `project` directory.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. This works for me. This script is part of a multi-language, multi-script project, so I need to run it at terminal outside Rstudio.